# opening a Java socket vs. Telnet?

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

If I execute the following code (NOTE: not the real IP address being used)

```
Socket s = new Socket("120.200.100.111", 80);
s.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
in.readLine();
```

After 10 seconds, I get 'SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out'

But if I telnet, I get:

```
telnet> open 120.200.100.111 80
Trying 120.200.100.111...
Connected to foo.bar.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Please note I am aware that for a full application I should use some sort of existing API for socket communications, but shouldn't the above test be getting some sort of timely response from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't the above test be getting some sort of timely response from the server?

No. A Telnet exchange doesn't start with the server sending you anything. *You* have to send something. The server is waiting for you; you are waiting for it; you're the one with the read timeout, so you get a read timeout.

The Telnet client doesn't use read timeouts by default.

Comment: In this particular case, the server is meant to be sending a 'Welcome Message'.  Is it correct to assume it should spit that out as soon as I connect, without me sending anything?

Comment: @George Obviously not. The Telnet client didn't see it either. Try sending a carriage return.

Comment: confirmed Server is not fulfilling the contract. Thanks for your help.